# Prove there is no such analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Please help prove that there is no analytic function on $z=0$ such that
$$ n^{-\frac3 2}<\left|f\left(\frac1 n\right)\right|<2n^{-\frac3 2}$$ for every natural $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the continuity of $f$, we must have $f(0) = 0$. Clearly, $f$ cannot be identically $0$. Since $f(0) = 0$ and $f$ is not identically zero, we can find another function $g$ that is analytic on $z = 0$ so that $f(z) = z^k g(z)$ for some positive integer $k$ and $g(0) \ne 0$.

It follows that for every $n \in \mathbb N$:
$$
\frac{1}{n^{3/2}} < \left|\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^k g\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right| < \frac{2}{n^{3/2}}
$$

Thus:
$$
n^{k - 3/2} < \left|g\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right| < 2n^{k - 3/2}
$$

If $k = 1$, we must have $g(0) = 0$ by the second inequality, a contradiction. If $k > 1$, we must have $\lim_{n\to\infty} g(1/n) = \infty$ by the first inequality, another contradiction. It follows that such a function $f$ cannot exist.

Comment: Just a little question, if $k = \frac{3}{2}$ doesn't that bound $g(\frac{1}{n})$ between 1 and 2?

Comment: @kvmu $k$ must be a positive integer. Check out [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_(complex_analysis)).